# How to remove error space under TextFormField Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I created TextFormField inside a Container and tried to hide an error line from TextFormField, but it's not working. Is there any way to delete it?

[My TextFormField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDrd5.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPSnr.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:
the border color for errorBorder & focusedErrorBorder could be changed.

```dart
            TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  //Do something with the user input.
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
                  ),
                  focusedErrorBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 0.0),
                  )),),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean the space under TextFormField. I don't want a default error text, but I use TextFormField validator, so I hide the error text, but it still has the space under it.

Sorry for my broken English.